# Windows XP Display is Stretched

Tags: display

I recently upgraded my CRT with a 19.5 Inches LCD Monitor. The trouble is that the display has become stretched even at the maximum resolution.

I am currently using Win XP SP2. Do I need to get any drivers from Microsoft ?

I am using the default Graphic card that comes on the mother board.

Comment: Expect to see this moved to SuperUser pretty soon. And why are you still on SP2?

Answer (score 2):

right click on the desktop, select **Properties** > **Settings** > **Advanced** > **Monitor**.

clear the box **Hide all modes that this monitor cannot display** and **Apply**.

now check your available resolutions again.

Answer (score 1):

Some older on board video cards only support 4:3 ratios.  (800x600, 1024x768, 1280x1024)  You may need to buy a newer video card or barring that, find a setting that puts black bars on the sides of you new screen.

I've seen this very thing happen with an LG LCD, and the user has been living with it for 4 months now.  It gives me a headeche just thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your motherboard's graphics chip can't handle the new screen's native resolution. More details on the new monitor, old monitor and motherboard would help a lot with any reply.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like Windows has not detected that you have changed your screen and it is keeping a resolution that is higher than the maximum, your screen has a higher resolution than the motherboard supports or not all video modes are being sent by the monitor (or possibly more).

What I recommend you do is take a look at the monitor specifications and see what the maximum resolution is and if you do not see this as an option, go to advanced and tick the box "Enable all screen modes" (or similar), and then set it.

If it does not work, you may be out of luck, but try upgrading graphic card drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Many older video cards didn't support widescreen resolutions when they were released. Many have had this added through a driver update. I would check and see if there is a driver update available for your card.

Examples of 4:3 resolution : 800x600, 1024x768, 1280x1024

Examples of 16x10 resolution : 1440x900, 1680x1050, 1920x1200

If you only see the 4:3 resolutions then this is your problem.