# Can't install Win XP over Vista/Ubuntu

Tags: windows-xp, setup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t install Win XP over Vista/Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/105072/cant-install-win-xp-over-vista-ubuntu)

I have Toshiba Satellite Laptop which had Vista home edition preinstalled on it. I installed the latest Ubuntu on top of it. Now I want to remove both Vista and Ubuntu from it and install Win XP and Fedora on it. The trouble is I can't run the Win XP installer from inside Vista. Fair enough. So I changed the boot option from BIOS and made it boot from the Win XP CD. The system starts booting up but ends at the Caldera DOS Screen :-(. It also says No FAT32 file system found. However it can detect the drives in DOS mode.

It pops up a console window with a: as its root directory. From their onward, I can see various directories and use DOS commands :( but when I run Win XP setup, it says that it can't run in Non graphical mode.

Please help.

This is a licensed version of Win XP.

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/105072/cant-install-win-xp-over-vista-ubuntu
(yes I know this was first, but the other has more answers).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any data from the disk, boot from a Linux repair CD, or Knoppix, and dd junk over the beginning of the disk as root

something like

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda

or

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hda

depending on the disk being SATA or PATA. It only needs to run for a few seconds, then you can stop it with control c.

I'd guess either the boot loader or the partition table is confusing the XP installer.